# HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream in NSUrlRequest

Tags: ios, httpwebrequest, xamarin, nsurlrequest

The problem is next: I have a project for iPhone in Xamarin. In this project I have file storage which sometimes synchronized with server data base. Synchronization use the following scheme: I form HttpWebRequest, add headers and call BeginGetRequestStream. Аfter this I parse stream from EndGetRequestStream in callback, add it to request as a body and call BeginGetResponse with this request. In response callback I parse stream from EndGetResponse and write data to file storage. It works fine. But not I need to remake this scheme by using NSUrlRequest and NSUrlSession, so I can put synchronization in background. The problems begins with BeginGetRequestStream whereby I receive body for request. How I can receive this stream with NSUrlRequest?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, What is the reason for wanting to move from HttpWebRequest to NSUrlResquest?

Comment: Because I want to put synchronization into background. As I read here http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/ios_backgrounding_with_tasks/ in iOs 7 "...the task run time is not longer continuous. Developers are encouraged to use the NSURlSession API to handle network transfers."